# Jquery uploadify not working on dynamicly created html

Tags: jquery, uploadify

I've tried a few solutions but not getting anywhere with this.

my code:

```
$(document).find("div[id^='subreply-']").live('click', function(){
            var num = this.id.split('-')[1];
            $('#subboxes-' + num).toggle();

            //live query
            $('.file_upload1-' + num).livequery(function(){

            $(this).uploadify({
                'uploader'  : 'js/uploadify.swf',
                'script'    : 'js/uploadify.php',
                'cancelImg' : 'js/cancel.png',
                'folder'    : 'upload',
                'auto'      : true,
                'onComplete' : function(event, queueID, fileObj, response, data) {

                                            $("#commentfile" + num).val(fileObj.name);
                                       }
                      });
                    })
            });
```

Im getting it to load on the first link that is being clicked to show a form, but it does not upload when I try to upload. Also when I click on the next link to load a form it does not generate uploadify.

The example html loaded will look similar to this:

```
<div id="subreply-1">Link to show form</div>

<div id="subboxes-1">
 <form >
 <input class="file_upload1-1" name="file_upload" type="file" />
 <input type="submit" />
 </form>
</div>

<div id="subreply-2">Link to show form</div>

<div id="subboxes-2">
 <form >
 <input class="file_upload1-1" name="file_upload" type="file" />
 <input type="submit" />
 </form>
</div>

<div id="subreply-3">Link to show form</div>

<div id="subboxes-3">
 <form >
 <input class="file_upload1-1" name="file_upload" type="file" />
 <input type="submit" />
 </form>
</div>
```

Thanks, hope I explained it well enough.

Comment: Dont create it in run time. Try to initialize one time and reuse it by hide and show.

Comment: Thanks guys but I found the solution, I had to change the class="file_upload1-1" to id="file_upload1-1" in the html and in jquery just change it to use a id. That worked :)